# Fetching image from url in Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to Fetch image from Url,  but i'm getting I/O exception.
I really have no idea why.

```
 try {
        URL profilePicUrl =  new URL("http://houssup.netau.net/vivek_thumbnail.jpg");

        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) profilePicUrl.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);


        connection.connect();

        InputStream inputStreamImage = connection.getInputStream();

        Bitmap profileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStreamImage);

        holder.profilePic.setImageBitmap(profileImage);


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Profile Image","Error in URL");
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Profile Image","Error in IO");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also i want to make point that, HttpURLconnection is throwing exception everywhere in my app. I mean in every class, I am not able to use this class.

Comment: Have you tried using a proper image loading library like Picasso? It would significantly simplify the problem here

Comment: ok, i will try that. But solution to the problem is still needed

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. That url is fine, so are there any exceptions in the logcat? Does the code not compile? What exactly is the problem? Please [edit] your question to tell us so we can accurately help you.

Comment: i mentioned that it throws I/O exception

Comment: i mentioned that it throws I/O exception

Comment: Okay, great, you should edit the question to include the logcat, then, you can read about creating a [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that code and the error is this:

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

so the solution is to include this on your code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: The better solution would be to just do the networking on a seperate thread